# Why did my profile picture disappear?

Tags: discussion, support, user-interface, images, profile-page

I discovered few days ago that my profile picture is gone, had to reupload it.
Did anybody else encounter this? Do you know the reason?

Comment: If you used a Facebook profile picture, it could have been due to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355805/default-profile-picture-from-facebook-is-being-displayed-instead-of-facebook-pi . (However, note that Firefox users such as myself do not see *any* Facebook profile pictures on SE at all, as they are blocked because of tracking protection. Hence anyone who actually wants their profile picture to be seen by others should better upload it directly to SE.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek So this is actually SE-wide, thanks for pointing it out. Not sure what is better - provide an answer (if you would) or just close it, as this is not MO-specific...